Repositorio Local GIT Proyecto Django
esta es mi primer consulta, puesto que voy iniciando, agradezco de antemano su comprensión por si es algo demasiado sencillo.
Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto con Django, y debo gestionarlo con GIT, mi duda es, al generar la carpeta para el repositorio local, es la misma que la carpeta de mi proyecto Django, o debe ser otra carpeta, y si es otra, supongo que debería estar fuera de la carpeta de mi proyecto ¿cierto?

Tu puedes crear tu proyecto y subirlo al repositorio de la forma en que te parezca mas conveniente pero en mi experiencia personal prefiero subir todo lo relacionado al proyecto a nivel raíz es decir sin carpetas que no corresponden al proyecto esto hace ver el repositorio mas limpio y menos confuso, ya en tu ordenador si puedes separar esos proyectos por carpetas sin la necesidad de subir esas carpetas a git, te explico de la siguiente forma.
Si haces el git init dentro de la carpeta que contiene tu proyecto Django (por ejemplo, archivos_django), Git rastreará directamente los archivos de ese proyecto.
Al subirlo al repositorio remoto, verás solo los archivos y carpetas del proyecto Django en el nivel raíz del repositorio.

Si decides crear una carpeta raíz, por ejemplo, mi_proyecto, y dentro de esa carpeta colocas tu proyecto Django (archivos_django), entonces haces el git init en mi_proyecto.
Esto subirá tanto la carpeta del proyecto Django como cualquier otro archivo o carpeta que esté en mi_proyecto.


Te agradezco mucha la información, me ha sido de gran ayuda. @ispr
